# Mavericks: library not found for -lwfdb

Tags: c, linker, clang, header-files, osx-mavericks

Moving from `10.8` to `10.9` broke my [WFDB](http://physionet.incor.usp.br/physiotools/wfdb.shtml) installation, **library not found for `-lwfdb`**.

This program

```
#include <wfdb/wfdb.h>
int main(void) { return 0; }
```

errors on linking (since Mavericks, `-I/usr/include` has to be included, otherwise the *compiler* errors):

```
567 ~/  clang -I/usr/include c.c -o c -lwfdb
ld: library not found for -lwfdb
```

---

I've tried also adding **`-L/usr/lib`** (where `libwfdb.10.5.20.dylib`, `libwfdb.10.dylib` and `libwfdb.dylib` are located), but `ld` still can't find `-lwfdb`,

Seems like Mavericks completely removed `gcc`. The `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` seems to be runtime-only. Everything worked under Mountain Lion. **What else should I try?**

---

## *A* solution

After perusing `clang`'s `-v`erbose output (continued below) ...

```
568 ~/  clang -v -I/usr/include c.c -o c -lwfdb
Apple LLVM version 5.0 (clang-500.2.79) (based on LLVM 3.3svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin13.0.0
Thread model: posix
 "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang" -cc1 -triple x86_64-apple-macosx10.9.0 -emit-obj -mrelax-all -disable-free -disable-llvm-verifier -main-file-name c.c -mrelocation-model pic -pic-level 2 -mdisable-fp-elim -masm-verbose -munwind-tables -target-cpu core2 -target-linker-version 224.1 -v -resource-dir /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/clang/5.0 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk -I /usr/include -fdebug-compilation-dir /Users/blaise/ -ferror-limit 19 -fmessage-length 170 -stack-protector 1 -mstackrealign -fblocks -fobjc-runtime=macosx-10.9.0 -fobjc-dispatch-method=mixed -fobjc-default-synthesize-properties -fencode-extended-block-signature -fdiagnostics-show-option -fcolor-diagnostics -o /var/folders/64/3l9hbm994q37l_bw79kf15bm0000gp/T/c-2iLIU4.o -x c c.c
clang -cc1 version 5.0 based upon LLVM 3.3svn default target x86_64-apple-darwin13.0.0
ignoring nonexistent directory "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/usr/local/include"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/Library/Frameworks"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/include
 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/clang/5.0/include
 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include
 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/usr/include
 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks (framework directory)
End of search list.
 "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ld" -demangle -dynamic -arch x86_64 -macosx_version_min 10.9.0 -syslibroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk -o c /var/folders/64/3l9hbm994q37l_bw79kf15bm0000gp/T/c-2iLIU4.o -lwfdb -lSystem /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/clang/5.0/lib/darwin/libclang_rt.osx.a
ld: library not found for -lwfdb
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

... I have placed `libwfdb.10.5.20.dylib` and `libwfdb.dylib` (`ln -s`ed to the 1st file) from `/usr/lib` inside `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/` in *its* `usr/lib`.

The program now links fine. **But, this surely can't be a long-term solution? What is the best way to proceed in 10.9?** E.g. adding a link to `/usr/lib` inside current `-syslibroot` would break on each Xcode upgrade ... no good.

Answer (score 2):

Try `clang -v -I/usr/include c.c -o c -lwfdb` for verbose output of what `clang` tries to do when searching for `-lwfdb`. Then, verify the files are there.

Comment: I've manually put the `wfdb` library inside the `ld`'s search-path; program now links. Have any suggestions for my updated question?

Comment: @courteous Why you don't like the `-L/path/to/library`?

Comment: Tried that already with no success: `-L/usr/lib` still failed at linking. (The attempt is in the question's history; just trying to keep it short.) And nonetheless, this lib surely isn't the only one broken under Mavericks ... this can't be *the* way forward. :)

Answer (score 0):

> Tried adding `/usr/include` to `$PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:`...

Well, that jut cannot work. `$PATH` is the search path for executables.

You should add `/usr/include` to the include path. Either via a compiler invocation - just add `-I/usr/include` to the command line - or in a `clang`-specific way I don't know about.

Comment: I did try the `-I/usr/include` invocation. Now, the `fatal error: 'wfdb/wfdb.h' file not found` is gone, but the `-l` option still triggers linker error: `ld: library not found for -lwfdb`.

Comment: @courteous Then additionally add the path to the library to the linker path - with `-L`.